# JSON De-serialisation with jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have JSON which looks like this:

```
{
  "totalSize": 11,
  "done": true,
  "records": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "Team_Member",
        "url": "/services/data/Team_Member/xxxx"
      },
      "Age": 48,
      "Birth_Date": "1971-05-17",
      "Business": null,
      "Citizenship": null,
      "Country": "UK",
      ...other fields...
    },
    { other records ....}
  ]
}
```

The objects in the records array can be of different types, but will not be mixed. During de-serialisation, the attributes field can be ignored.

I am trying to de-serialize it with jackson into this Java class:

```
@lombok.Data
public class QueryResult<C extends BaseObject> {
    private int totalSize;
    private boolean done;
    private List<C> records;
}
```

And sub-classses of BaseObject will have the required fields, example:

```
public class TeamMember extends BaseObject {
    public int Age;
    public Date Birth_Date;
    //etc...
}
```

Here is the de-serialization code:

```
public <C extends BaseObject> QueryResult<C> doQuery(Class<C> baseObjectClass) {

    String json = ...get json from somewhere
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionLikeType(QueryResult.class, baseObjectClass);
        return mapper.readValue(json, type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

But this is not successful, I get the exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a Value deserializer for type [collection-like type; class com.foo.QueryResult, contains [simple type, class com.foo.TeamMember]]
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First parameter name in method [constructCollectionLikeType](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html#constructCollectionLikeType-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-) is `collectionClass` so it must be a collection type: `ArrayList`, for example.

You need to use [constructParametricType](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html#constructParametricType-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class...-) method.

```
JavaType queryType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(QueryResult.class, TeamMember.class);
QueryResult<TeamMember> queryResult = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, queryType);
```